# libjpeg jpeg_stdio_dest() seg fault

Tags: c

Hello I have a little problem with writting data to jpeg:

Here is the code snippet:

```
struct jpeg_compress_struct cinfo;
struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
/* More stuff */
FILE * outfile;                /* target file */
JSAMPROW row_pointer[1];        /* pointer to JSAMPLE row[s] */
int row_stride;                /* physical row width in image buffer */

cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);
jpeg_create_compress(&cinfo);


if ((outfile = fopen(filename, "wb+")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "can't open %s\n", filename);
    exit(1);
}
else
    printf("File successfully opened\n");

jpeg_stdio_dest(&cinfo, outfile);

cinfo.image_width = img_w;
cinfo.image_height = img_h;
cinfo.input_components = 3;
cinfo.in_color_space = JCS_RGB;
```

It gives me a segfault on jpeg_stdio_dest, gdb output:

#0  0x00007ffff7855735 in malloc_consolidate () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

#1  0x00007ffff7856a08 in _int_malloc () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

#2  0x00007ffff7858cc0 in malloc () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

#3  0x00007ffff7bb4b17 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.8

#4  0x00007ffff7b9f225 in jpeg_stdio_dest () from /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.8

#5  0x0000000000400f2e in write_jpeg_file (
 image_buffer=0x608070 "\002\002\002\002\002\002\366\366\366\365\365\365\001\001\001\003 \003\003\371\371\371\367\367\367\362\362\362\361\361\361\002\002\002\003\003\003\373\373\373\373\373\373\001\001\001\002\002\002", img_h=4, img_w=4, filename=0x7fffffffe6d1 "lol.jpg", quality=100) at jpegapi.c:39

#6  0x0000000000400e1f in main (argc=5, argv=0x7fffffffe2e8) at main.c:28

I have no idea where to search, any help is appreciated

Comment: Why not start debugging at `main.c:28` ?

Comment: main.c:28 is the call of write_jpeg_file that contain the snippet from above...

Answer (score 0):

The file opening can fail and yet you do a jpeg_stdio_dest call

bracket problem?

```
if ((outfile = fopen(filename, "wb+")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "can't open %s\n", filename);
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    printf("File successfully opened\n");
    jpeg_stdio_dest(&cinfo, outfile);
}
```

Comment: If opening fail, progam will exit via exit(1). Also, with segfault I receive the message that file was successfully opened.

Comment: it's a call from dynamically linked jpeglib, gdb can't look into it since it's not compiled with debug symbols...

Comment: what rights does that function need in order to write it to the output file? what happens if you get rid of the binary file permission?

Comment: I'm using this example: https://github.com/Windower/libjpeg/blob/master/example.c as you can see, comment tells me that "b" is necessary to be added.